# Creating an SKShapeNode from CGPoint array that starts and ends on the edges of the screen rect

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Okay, so I am working on my first iOS game using SpriteKit and Swift, and I am having a hard time finding a good way to accomplish this one task. I am trying to figure out how to take a CGPoint array that basically contains a user-made path going from one edge of the screen to another. I want to figure out the best way to fill in this space, perhaps with an SKShapeNode but maybe theres a better way. One important condition is to determine which side of path will get filled, and this should be determined based on whether the ball in the game is in that area; I want to make it so that the area where there is no ball gets filled in. I was thinking of making an SKShapeNode so I could check if the current position of the ball is inside that node, but I realized I'm not sure how to figure out how to set up the node so that it is put against the edges of the screen. The only thing I can think of is adding the screen corners but it would probably get really messed up if I added all of them, so I want to know what the best way to do this would be. I started writing this function but just got stuck and have no idea what to do now:

```
func fillInPolgyon(contactPoint: CGPoint) {
    var frameContactPoint = contactPoint

    if contactPoint.x < 3 && contactPoint.x > -3 {
        frameContactPoint.x = 0
    }
    else if contactPoint.y < 3 && contactPoint.y > -3 {
        frameContactPoint.y = 0
    }
    //println("ship hit bounds: \(frameContactPoint)")

    var polygonPath = UIBezierPath(CGPath: createTrailPath()!)
    polygonPath.addLineToPoint(frameContactPoint)
    polygonPath.closePath()

    var polygonPathCG = polygonPath.CGPath
    var ballLocation = ball.position

    if !polygonPath.containsPoint(ballLocation) {
        let filledPolygonNode = SKShapeNode(path: polygonPathCG)
        filledPolygonNode.name = FilledPolygonName
        filledPolygonNode.fillColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 1, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        addChild(filledPolygonNode)
        filledPolygonNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeChainFromPath: polygonPathCG)
        filledPolygonNode.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = FilledPolygon
        filledPolygonNode.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ShipCategory | BallCategory
        filledPolygonNode.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
        var trailPoints: [CGPoint] = [contactPoint]
    }
}
```

Clearly what I have here sucks... it doesn't fill out the corners of the screen and also, even though I have it checking to make sure it doesn't have the same contact point passed through it (this function is called whenever the path hits the walls of the screen through the didBeginContact function), but the points will be slightly different anyways, resulting in the creation of way too many unwanted nodes, causing major performance issues. So, does anyone have any ideas??? Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can store `CGPoint` as a `NSString` object by `NSStringFromCGPoint(point)` function.

Comment: I don't understand how that would help. What would that do for me?